# Multiple models in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've got 2 models with the same name, but in different folders.

```
models
   |
   - model1
        |
        - db_model.php
   |
   - model2
        |
        - db_model.php
```

When I load them like this it causes a problem:

```
$this->load->model('model1/db_model', 'db_model1');
$this->load->model('model2/db_model', 'db_model2');
```

Comment: I think you should give different names while you are loading

Comment: yeah, i think i should. but anyway, it's strange, 'cause i provide different name as second var.

Comment: what happen when `$this->load->model('model2/db_model', 'db_model2');` ?

Comment: @eicto, the previous model stays loaded

Comment: you want to unload it ?

Comment: @eicto, no, need to access it any time, like previous one.

Comment: so what was the problem ? use 1st one as `$this->db_model->method()` and second as `$this->db_model2->method()`

Comment: actually, i can't load the second one, if load it from the same filename. if I change filename and model class - then it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'db_model' is an alias, so you are naming them both the same thing.

Are you doing that for a reason? Explain what you want and we'll help with a workaround

Comment: No reason. They just named the same but located in different folders. I wonder why I can't load them that way, providing another alias as second parameter.

Comment: you should be able to. you are giving them both the same alias, is your problem

The system loads them by the alias name, and no longer realizes they are in two different folders.